# MacOS Sonoma and Docker Issues

Tags: docker-compose, macos-sonoma

I updated Sonoma on my MacBook Pro. Now when I try to do a compose build I get the following errors:

```
ERROR [db-crm internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/postgres:15.2 
ERROR [dbpool-crm internal] load metadata for docker.io/brainsam/pgbouncer:latest

failed to solve: postgres:15.2: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fpostgres%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized
```

I uninstalled Docker and re-installed the latest version of the Apple Silicon version of Docker (4.24.0 (122432)), but the problem still persists.  Doing some Google, but haven't found a solution to the issue.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I have a 2021 Apple M1 Max with 32GB and 2TB drive.

Comment: did you try `docker login` ?

Comment: WHAT, omg that was it.  What I don't get is the Docker Desktop, I am logged in.  Is there a difference between the two?  In either case that solved my issue - Thank you

Comment: Great! I'm not a Mac user, but I've gotten that error before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Mac user, but I've gotten that error before.

try running:

```
docker login
```

Comment: Learned something new today.  Thank you